# One to Zero...One Master Detail in Lightswitch HTML Client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Creating a master detail with this relationship:

Parent (1) ---> Child(0 or 1)

The details page shows the child record greyed out.

I realise this is because Lightswitch doesn't know if it should create a record.

When trying to add an existing method, "Add/Edit Child" is not available.

Question is, what javascript code do I put in a button to create the child record?

Or is there another way to do this with maintaining this relationship structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple ways you can do this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2013/05/09/saving-data-across-one-to-one-relationships.aspx

HTH,
-Beth